# how to provide routes for a function in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My controller,

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    // connectionLimit : 100, //important
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'socialwiki'
});
connection.connect(function(error) {
    if (!!error) {
        console.log('error');

    } else {
        console.log('connected');
    }
});
exports.getlist = function(req, res) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM     profile", function(error, result, rows, fields) {
        if (!!error) {
            console.log('fail');
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

I am trying to provide routes at my routes folder,
user.js

```
var express = require('express');
var admin = require('../controllers/user');
//Here i created my controller path to admin but i am not sure how to provide routes for my getlist function.
```

I am completely new to express js can someone suggest help please.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're trying to do here, do you have routes in `user.js` that you're trying to use, if so what do they look like, or are you trying to create routes, or ... ?

Comment: yes i want to create routes for my function in user.js

Comment: Please read docs, its very clear described https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

Define a get route :

```
var app = express();
app.get('/users', admin.getlist);
```

The get method let you define a route for the get http method.
You just have to pass your getlist function as the argument.

Take a look at the expressjs documentation : http://expressjs.com/fr/guide/routing.html

Comment: how can i display my result with routes

Comment: /var/www/html/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn));
      ^

Comment: you can return your results with :
    res.send(result);

Answer (score 1):

You can create route so many types this is the simplest form of route in express

```
var exress=require('express');

var app=express();

app.get('/hello',function(req,res){
res.send('Hello GET route')
})

app.post('/hello',function(req,res){
res.send('Hello POST route')
})
```

as what I guess you want to get this result in your GET Call

```
app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM     profile", function(error, result, rows, fields) {
    if (!!error) {
      console.log('fail');
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
}
```